# Xamarin: Can I do in a cross platform project the "Android part" and do IOS when the rest is finish?

Tags: xamarin

I have a project in `Android Studio` (on a pc), and as far as I know now `Microsoft` owns `Xamarin` and its free once you have a `Visual Studio` license, then you can develop apps using `C#`(Already know that I have to port the `JAVA` code) and then compile in a `MAC` the `IOS` app.

My 2 concerns are:

When you can't compile, will the `IDE` show the `IOS` related errors?

There is a clear implementation of *"cross platform code"* vs *"specific code"*?
How `Xamarin` manage it?

In addition, our plan is to finish the app for Android which is our primary target and then manage the `IOS`, besides the other questions, what I need to know is if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the VS IDE will show you build errors from the iOS build server.

Yes, you can build an Android app using Xamarin and later extend it to build an iOS app also.  This is easiest if you use Xamarin Forms, but it also possible with native Android/iOS UI, but will be much more dependent on how you architect your applications.